# do conditional things in noscript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, noscript

Good day,

I have a function inside a javaScript file. I have 10 button will trigger this function to do something based on the button name. The code is something as follow:

```
function doSomething( name ){

  switch(name){
    case "1";
      alert("i am 1");
      break;
    case "2";
      alert("i am 1");
      break;
   // and so on...
  }
}
```

This `doSomething` is working fine. However, I would like to alert other things when there is `noscript` or `JavaScript` is disable.

I do something like:

```
<noscript>
  // if click on button 1, display <image src="image/img1" />
  // if click on button 2, display <image src="image/img2" />
  // and so on..
  // I would like display different image when different button clicked.
</noscript>
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

No way. HTML5 itself is just a document sturcture and CSS3 provides style. That is, HTML5 *as is* has no behavior, thus, you won't be able to interact with the document without JavaScript.

If JavaScript is disabled and you provide a `<noscript>` element, you should tell your users that your Web application won't work without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the checkbox hack in css to show a message in a hidden div, Style the labels like your buttons.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
 
label {
    
    background: #08C;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
 .to-be-changed {display:none;}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .to-be-changed {
    display:block;
 margin-top:30px;
 font-size:120%;
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<noscript>
  <div id="buttons">
  <input type="checkbox" id="button1"><label for="button1">button 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="button2"><label for="button2">button 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="button3"><label for="button3">button 3</label>
 <div class="to-be-changed"> You need to have javascript activated for the buttons to work !</div>
  </div>
</noscript>
```

Obviously turn js off to se it working. Here's a link to the page I got the info from [Css click events](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/)

Comment: To hide the other buttons (so you don't have 2 sets on the page ) when there's no js put a noscript div with display none around them.i.e `<noscript><div id="buttons-when-js-turned-on"></noscript>` then close the div in a noscript at the bottom of the buttons and add display:none to the css.

Comment: Hi Billy. But I am working on a button instead of checkbox. And I already edit something on my question. kindly advise again : )